# How to select rows by group if years are next to each other in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':['cust1', 'cust1', 'cust2', 'cust3', 'cust3', 'cust4', 'cust4'],
                   'date':[date(2019, 1, 20), date(2020, 6, 15), date(2017, 1, 10), date(2015, 6, 12), date(2017, 12, 15), date(2018, 12, 10), date(2017, 1, 5)]
                   })

       a        date
0  cust1  2019-01-20
1  cust1  2020-06-15
2  cust2  2017-01-10
3  cust3  2015-06-12
4  cust3  2017-12-15
5  cust4  2018-12-10
6  cust4  2017-01-05
```

I would like to select all rows by group in column 'a' if the year in 'date' column is "back to back" or next to each other (ie. no gap between years) and there are minimum 2 different dates per group in 'a'.

the resulting dataframe should look like this.

```
       a        date
0  cust1  2019-01-20
1  cust1  2020-06-15
5  cust4  2018-12-10
6  cust4  2017-01-05
```

explanation: row 2 is not selected because group 'cust2' has only 1 year/date. group 'cust3' is not select because there is a "gap" between years 2015 and 2017.

Comment: Why don't you include row4 in the results (even though it's from a consecutive year from row5)? Is it because it's from a different group from row5?

Comment: yes. i only want to look within groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `date` column to pandas datetime series, then use [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) to group the `year` on column `a` and use `diff` to get successive differences, then `shift` + `ffill`, and finally use `abs` + `Series.eq` to create a boolean mask `m`, use this mask to filter the rows:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
m = df['date'].dt.year.groupby(df['a']).apply(lambda x: x.diff().shift(-1).ffill()).abs().eq(1)
df1 = df[m]
```

Result:

```
print(df1)
       a       date
0  cust1 2019-01-20
1  cust1 2020-06-15
5  cust4 2018-12-10
6  cust4 2017-01-05
```

Comment: nice solution. can i do it as 1 liner without the mask?

Comment: You can but it will not look so nice, and will affect readibility..

Comment: This solution won't work if the first three dates, all from cust1, are date(2015, 6, 15), date(2019, 1, 20), date(2020, 6, 15),

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `groupby` and `shift`, in several steps for clarity:

```
df["year"] = pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.year
df["adjacent"] = (df.groupby("a")["year"].diff().abs() == 1) | (df.groupby("a")["year"].diff(-1).abs() == 1)
res = df[df.adjacent]
```

Output:

```
       a       date  year    adjacent
0  cust1 2019-01-20  2019    True
1  cust1 2020-06-15  2020    True
5  cust4 2018-12-10  2018    True
6  cust4 2017-01-05  2017    True
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?